# sprintf crashes but it is unclear why

Tags: c, printf

I tried the following code with `sprintf`, but it crashes in some cases and works fine in the other. Could anyone explain it to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
       //char *s = malloc(20); //works fine
       //char *s = "";         //does not work, no matter what the initial value is
       char s[20];       //works fine
       sprintf(s, "%s", "hello world");
       printf("%s",s);
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing this:

```
char *s = "";
```

or

```
char *s = "longer string";
```

You are creating a literal string which is possibly placed in read-only memory. So you **cannot change** it later.

If you try to do the following syntax:

```
char s[] = "...";
```

the array will be initialized with the literal string and you will be able to modify the original array later.

Suggested questions on site:

1. [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)
2. [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with “char *s” but not “char s[]”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)